# How to bind command to dynamic context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, prism

I am using c#, prism, wpf. I want to create a context list dynamically within a listview, such as the following picture:

[image]

When I click those menu item, that will callback to my custom function. In that function I can identify which menu item is clicked, for example, I can get the header of the menu item.

I tried to add a command tag and bind to a ICommand. But there is no response when I clicked it.

I have read different example from web, but they never shows the implementation of xaml and viewmodel at the same time. I would like to ask how to do it? Thank you very much.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindowView, MainWindowViewModel>();
```

Following is my xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceObjects}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LstBoxItemStyleNormal}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServiceName}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuList}">
                            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuName}" Command="{Binding ConfirmButtonCommand}"/>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Following is my viewmodel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public class MenuNode : BindableBase
    {
        private string _menuName;
        public string MenuName
        {
            get => _menuName;
            set => SetProperty(ref _menuName, value);
        }
    }
    public class ServiceNode : BindableBase
    {
        private string _serviceName;
        public string ServiceName
        {
            get => _serviceName;
            set => SetProperty(ref _serviceName, value);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<MenuNode> ContextMenuList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuNode>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceNode> ServiceObjects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ServiceNode>();
    
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ServiceNode tempNode = new ServiceNode { ServiceName = "AP", State = "Normal" };
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "A Item" });
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "B Item" });
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "C Item" });
            ServiceObjects.Add(tempNode);
        }
        ConfirmButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(HandleConfirmButtonCommand);
    }
    public ICommand ConfirmButtonCommand { get; }

    private void HandleConfirmButtonCommand()
    {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I used at the end. Thanks

In App.xaml.cs:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindowView, MainWindowViewModel>();
```

Following is my xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceObjects}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LstBoxItemStyleNormal}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServiceName}" Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuList}">
                            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuName}"
                                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ConfirmButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                                              CommandParameter="Binding MenuName"/>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Following is my viewmodel:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public class MenuNode : BindableBase
    {
        private string _menuName;
        public string MenuName
        {
            get => _menuName;
            set => SetProperty(ref _menuName, value);
        }
    }
    public class ServiceNode : BindableBase
    {
        private string _serviceName;
        public string ServiceName
        {
            get => _serviceName;
            set => SetProperty(ref _serviceName, value);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<MenuNode> ContextMenuList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuNode>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceNode> ServiceObjects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ServiceNode>();
    
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ServiceNode tempNode = new ServiceNode { ServiceName = "AP", State = "Normal" };
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "A Item" });
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "B Item" });
            tempNode.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuNode { MenuName = "C Item" });
            ServiceObjects.Add(tempNode);
        }
        ConfirmButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(HandleConfirmButtonCommand);
    }
    public ICommand ConfirmButtonCommand { get; }

    private void HandleConfirmButtonCommand(string parameter)
    {
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all binding to `Command` for `MenuItem` should be curly brackets: `{Binding ConfirmButtonCommand}`.
Second, your command is defined in `MainWindowViewModel` class, while `DataContext` for `MenuItem` is `MenuNode`, so the command can't be found.
The simplest fix is - give name to `List` and when binding to command, refer to its `DataContext`.
For example:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="list" ...>
```

and then

```xml
<MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuName}" Command="{Binding DataContext.ConfirmButtonCommand, ElementName=list}"/>
```

Also, probably for the command you'll need also to know on what `ServiceNode` it was clicked, and you can pass it via `CommandParameter` (fetching `DataContext` from `ContextMenu` that holds `MenuItem`):

```xml
<MenuItem ... CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I missed to mention that I am using `ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindowView, MainWindowViewModel>();`
Also, after I add the `{}`, there is no more exception throw, but also there is no callbacks to the function `HandleConfirmButtonCommand`.
Also, what is the function declaration should be? If I want to get the information about the who is the caller ?
Since I am new to C# wpf and prism, I really don't know where to start. Thanks

Comment: Have you changed binding to `Command` in `MenuItem` as I suggested? `ViewModelLocationProvider` has nothing to do with `DataContext` in wpf. To get caller - add `CommandParameter` as I suggested and change your command to `DelegateCommand<ServiceMode>`.

Comment: BTW, if your context menu is the same for all `ServiceMode` instances and is not changing in time, it may be better to move context menu to `MainWindowViewModel` or even to xaml.